# Index/match referencing to column name

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I've tried to create a code which could handle my complex set of data which will be highly dynamic. There are two workbooks, both will change in terms of numbers of rows and columns. However, the columns which is of my interest will have names which will not change over time.

My aim is get the name from one workbooks/worksheet based on a code represented in both workbooks.

So for I have named the columns of interest which will be included in the index/match formula but don't how to progress from that.
Problem 1: How to setup the formula
problem 2: How to reference to the matching cell

Here the Code:

```
sub indeD()
    Dim selRange As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim ColKod As Integer
    Dim CWS As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Range

    'Find the column number where the column header is
    Set CWB = Workbooks("teknikersenast")
    Set CWS = CWB.Worksheets("Data")
    ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Efternamn", CWS.Rows(1), 0)
    ColKod = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Teknikerskod", CWS.Rows(1), 0)
  
    'Set the column range to work with
    Set selRange = CWS.Columns(ColNum)
    Set TRange = CWS.Columns(ColKod)
     
    Workbooks("Maptivexx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("F2").FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=INDEX(selRange,MATCH(Workbooks("Maptivexx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("E2"),TRange,0))"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(" & selRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & ",MATCH(" & Workbooks("Maptivexx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E2").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & "," & TRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & ",0))"` as formula.

Comment: Thanks, tried but I get "application-defined or object-defined error"  on this part                                                                                                                    "Workbooks("Maptivexx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range    ("F2").FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=INDEX(" & selRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & ",MATCH(" & Workbooks("Maptivexx").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E2").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & "," & TRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True) & ",0))""

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting: Create the formula as a string and use `Debug.Print theFormula` to output it to the Immediate window in the VB editor.  Does it look as you expect? Can you manually enter that formula into the sheet?  If not, what error does it give you?